# How to get close price of bar when my boolean criteria is met?

Tags: pine-script

I've created some criteria that creates a shape on the chart; now I need to know if the close price of the next candle is higher than the close price of the candle where my `callSignal` shape occurs.

Currently getting this error, which makes sense:

```
line 177: Cannot call 'operator <' with arguments (series[bool], series[bool]); available overloads: <(float, float) => bool; <(input float, input float) => input bool; <(const float, const float) => const bool; <(float, series[float]) => series[bool]; <(series[float], float) => series[bool]; <(series[float], series[float]) => series[bool];
```

Here is my code:

```
// ... //
expiryLength = 1
callSignal = Cond1[1] ? na : Cond1 and rightTime? Cond1 : na
putSignal = Cond1[2] ? na : Cond2 and rightTime? Cond1 : na

plotshape(callSignal, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(putSignal, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny)

// This is the part I am struggling with... //
callWL = callSignal[expiryLength] < callSignal
plotshape(callWL, size=size.large)
```

I don't know how to incorporate `close` within my `callWL` variable, or if I just need to rework this further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample script that generates call entries whenever price crosses SMA 30 from below and after expiryLength bars, plots a shape for gain/loss.

```
//@version=4
study("Call lookback", overlay=true)

_expiryLength = input(title="Expire length in bars", type=input.integer, defval=10, minval=1)
_callSma = input(title="Call entry SMA period", type=input.integer, defval=30, minval=1)
_callSignal = false

// Make call entries
_callSignal := crossover(close, sma(close, _callSma))
plotshape(_callSignal?close:na, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.tiny)

// Lookback for call entry and draw a symbol for gain/loss
_callWL = _callSignal[_expiryLength]
_color = close > close[_expiryLength]?color.green:color.red
plotshape(_callWL?close:na, color=_color, size=size.tiny)

plot(sma(close, _callSma))
```